# After inserting data into database count the number of data and returns values like in 3 trainees

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I want to display the number of trainee right after Trainee is inserted into database in TextView.
Here is my code:
 Training class:

```
public void addTrainee(Trainee trainee){    

    // Inserting person details to the database is in separate method
    trainee.storeToDB();

    //Counting the number of participants 
    trainee.countTrainee(this.getId());

    // Create the link between the trainee and the training
    trainee.registerToTraining(this.getId());

    // Add the trainee to the attendance list of the current training object
    this.traineeArrayList.add(trainee);     
}
```

Trainee Class:

```
public int countTrainee(int training_id) {
    DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();

    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM" + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ATTENDANCE;
    Cursor cursor = db.select(countQuery);
    cursor.close();
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

My Activity Class:

```
countTrainee = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.traineeCount);
    countTrainee.setText(trainee.countTrainee(0));
```

I know I have done totally wrong. But can someone help me solving  this. Hope you understand what I am trying to do with this code.

Comment: You can't close cursor and then use `getCount()`!

Comment: Is that the only problem there?

Comment: No... Where is `training_id` used? What is `trainee.countTrainee(this.getId());` for? Is this [tag:Android]?

Comment: I am trying to count the number of trainees that are attending to the specific Training. That's why I am passing training_id. this.getId() is the Training Id.

Answer (score 0):

Training class:

```
//...
// Is this result supposed to be used anywhere???
trainee.countTrainee(this.getId());
//...
```

Trainee Class:

```
public int countTrainee(int training_id) {
    int cnt;
    DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
    Cursor cursor = db.select("SELECT * FROM" + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ATTENDANCE + " WHERE id="+training_id);
    cnt=cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close(); //Not sure if necessary...
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: I found the better solution to sole my problem. Actually, I can solve by just counting the array of list that I have like ArrayList.size(). Isn't it? Why was I querying the database.